# Transmission material is dark in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I created an eyeball from scratch. The eyeball requires a clear lens over the iris to be as accurate as possible. But when i enable full transparency in the principled BSDF, it renders slightly darker than I'd like. And the base color of the material is completely white... Help?

CYCLES:
[image]

EEVEE:
[image]

(and yes I know this question has been asked before but I feel like the answer should be updated as Blender continues to advance)

Comment: please show us your material setup...or provide blend-file